# display-content:space-around seems not to work on phone screens with my code

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

As a beginner in code (..and in English, but that is not the question!), I have some problem with a responsive code. This is an extract of yhe html code:

```
<footer class="footerDesktop">

        <p><a href="#">06 xx xx xx xx</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">xxxxxx@gmail.com</a></p>
        
      
</footer>
```

And this is the extract of the css code:

```
.footerDesktop {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  min-width: 720px;
  background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
  color: #777;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center; 

}


.footerDesktop p {
 
  width: 40%; 
  box-sizing: border-box;

  text-align: center;
  }

.footerDesktop a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;    
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #777;
  margin-bottom: -10;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  }
```

The code works with desktop screen but not with small ones. The phone number and mail are not both visible and not centered in small screens.  I thought that  display: flex and justify-content:space-around were responsive by nature.
I tried some media queries to manage small screens but failed in finding solutions.

Can you please help me?

Thanks for your help and tolerance in regards to a beginner!

Didier

I tried to use media queries but did not find how to correct my problem.

Comment: Add media query:
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .footerDesktop {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

Remove css:   min-width: 720px;
}

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a min-width of 720px, your footer will push out of your screen, so I would get rid of that.

Secondly, when you use "display: flex", the items within will stay on the same row unless specified otherwise, that's when you should use "flex-wrap: wrap". That basically says "if the items cannot be contained on one row, wrap them to a new line"

Finally, I think that's an obvious mistake I guess you already figured, but you should use units here. Also "a" tags are inline elements, so unless you change their display, they will not accept vertical spacing (padding-top, margin-bottom, ...)

```
margin-bottom: -10; /* px, em, ... */
padding-bottom: 0;
```

Here's something that should work with no media queries

```
.footerDesktop {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #777;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.footerDesktop p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 50%;
  margin: 0; /* default styles add a bit of margin on p elements, you may want to get rid of that */
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.footerDesktop a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;    
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #777;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for your help! My problem is solved and your answer helped me learning css !